# Jmeter: CSV data parameterize in script but not updated in system database

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have create CSV file for my script. That CSV file is working in script while scripts is running, Even debug sampler showing csv data correctly but in application database recorded data is not get replaced by CSV data.
for Example. In recorded script my booking branch is LA and Delivery branch is Seattle and In CSV 1st booking value is Dubai and delivery value is SA. 
after running the script debug sample and view result tree showing the CSV data i.e Dubai and SA but when we see the application database its taking only recorded value i.e LA and Seattle. Please tell me what would be the issue ? how can i resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace values, hard-coded during recording with the ones, defined in the CSV Data Set Config.

For instance, if you had something like:

[image: Recorded request]

And you have CSV Data Set Config like:

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

You'll need to amend the values to match JMeter variables like:

[image: Request with CSV variables]

In that case (given correct CSV Data Set configuration) parameters will be replaced with the values from CSV file. If not - follow troubleshooting tips:

- inspect *jmeter.log* file (usually lives in the /bin folder of your JMeter installation, can also be created in the folder where you launch JMeter from, i.e. if you run it from a shortcut)
- add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - it will allow to see JMeter Variables values

  [image]
- See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for detailed instructions on how to parametrise your JMeter test using CSV files as data sources.

Comment: Debug sampler showing me what i have passed through CSV file. But in system database that values are absent and showing recorded value only.